# R how to sort / reorder asnyc curl responses based on a list of requests?

Tags: r, libcurl

With the function **curl_fetch_multi**  I can do asynchronous http calls.

**multi_add** schedules requests which are executed concurrently when calling **multi_run**. For each successful request the done callback is triggered with response data. For failed requests (when curl_fetch_memory would raise an error), the fail function is triggered with the error message.

The problem is: I need to get the responses in **data** in the order I structured the curl_fetch_multi calls.

Here is an example:

```
data <- list()
success <- function(res){
  cat("Request done! Status:", res$status, "\n")
  data <<- c(data, list(res))
}
failure <- function(msg){
  cat("Oh noes! Request failed!", msg, "\n")
}

request_list<-c("http://google.de","http://httpbin.org/status/418","https://bing.com")

handles<-lapply(request_list,function(x)curl::curl_fetch_multi(x,success, failure))

curl::multi_run()
str(data)
```

The order of responses in **data** should be:

1. "http://google.de"
2. "http://httpbin.org/status/418"
3. "https://bing.com"

But wenn I run my code the order is random (as the responses):

```
List of 6
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ url        : chr "http://httpbin.org/status/418"
  ..$ status_code: int 418
  ..$ type       : chr NA
  ..$ headers    : raw [1:257] 48 54 54 50 ...
  ..$ modified   : POSIXct[1:1], format: NA
  ..$ times      : Named num [1:6] 0.0 2.1e-05 2.6e-05 5.4e-05 9.7e-02 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "redirect" "namelookup" "connect" "pretransfer" ...
  ..$ content    : raw [1:135] 0a 20 20 20 ...
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ url        : chr "https://www.bing.com:443/?toWww=1&redig=84D1B48D3B1948B4AD35DC4B4C69E5CE"
  ..$ status_code: int 200
  ..$ type       : chr "text/html; charset=utf-8"
  ..$ headers    : raw [1:3231] 48 54 54 50 ...
  ..$ modified   : POSIXct[1:1], format: NA
  ..$ times      : Named num [1:6] 0.040574 0.000046 0.000055 0.0002 0.116532 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "redirect" "namelookup" "connect" "pretransfer" ...
  ..$ content    : raw [1:113883] 3c 21 64 6f ...
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ url        : chr "http://www.google.de/"
  ..$ status_code: int 200
  ..$ type       : chr "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  ..$ headers    : raw [1:740] 48 54 54 50 ...
  ..$ modified   : POSIXct[1:1], format: NA
  ..$ times      : Named num [1:6] 0.100166 0.00007 0.00008 0.000177 0.25349 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "redirect" "namelookup" "connect" "pretransfer" ...
  ..$ content    : raw [1:13833] 3c 21 64 6f ...
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ url        : chr "http://www.google.de/"
  ..$ status_code: int 200
  ..$ type       : chr "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  ..$ headers    : raw [1:741] 48 54 54 50 ...
  ..$ modified   : POSIXct[1:1], format: NA
  ..$ times      : Named num [1:6] 0.11156 0.00481 0.01488 0.01499 0.257 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "redirect" "namelookup" "connect" "pretransfer" ...
  ..$ content    : raw [1:13890] 3c 21 64 6f ...
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ url        : chr "https://www.bing.com:443/?toWww=1&redig=4AE372C6991F4873A7C8D284E45599E2"
  ..$ status_code: int 200
  ..$ type       : chr "text/html; charset=utf-8"
  ..$ headers    : raw [1:3233] 48 54 54 50 ...
  ..$ modified   : POSIXct[1:1], format: NA
  ..$ times      : Named num [1:6] 0.14163 0.00135 0.01223 0.19156 0.27674 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "redirect" "namelookup" "connect" "pretransfer" ...
  ..$ content    : raw [1:113883] 3c 21 64 6f ...
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ url        : chr "http://httpbin.org/status/418"
  ..$ status_code: int 418
  ..$ type       : chr NA
  ..$ headers    : raw [1:257] 48 54 54 50 ...
  ..$ modified   : POSIXct[1:1], format: NA
  ..$ times      : Named num [1:6] 0 0.000699 0.091084 0.091118 1.357831 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "redirect" "namelookup" "connect" "pretransfer" ...
  ..$ content    : raw [1:135] 0a 20 20 20 ...
```

I tried sorting a list of lists (**data**) based on the ** handles** by matching the url, but the problem is; **handles** is a list of pointers.

Is there is maybe an option that I could use to bring the responses in order of calls?

One approach I tried was to match the element und create an Index so I can reorder the result based on this. But it does not seem to work.
Here is my approach :

```
order_of_response_elements<-match(request_list,sapply(data,'[[',1))
```